# Eclipse RCP: application specific folder

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have an RCP application in Eclipse 4.x for a cross-platform software. I would like to place the `osgi.instance.area` in the application specific folder. For example on Windows it generally is C:\Users[Username]\AppData[Name]. Something similar to the directories outlined here - http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory.

I have seen the solution here - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=241192 but I haven't understood it really well. I use the product editor on Eclipse and under the Configuration tab, I have added the osgi.instance.area property in the Properties section with another directory at the moment.

Then I tried the solution from the bug - `$APPDATA$/COMPANY/PROGRAM/instance` but I couldn't find the directory anywhere at the expected location. Also, how does this work for Linux and Mac OS X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows 7 and 8 $APPDATA$ is C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Roaming. In Linux $APPDATA$ is undefined. You should use @none, @noDefault, @user.home, @user.dir, filepath or url

Comment: Yes, that is what I worked out as well. In my case it actually created a directory in the application directory as APPDATA and added the corresponding directories... incase someone was wondering what the behaviour was.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the `osgi.instance.area.default` property that you should set. The value migght be something like `@user.home/Documents/workspace`

Comment: That is what I am using currently - `user.home` but I want to use the application specific folder defined by `$APPDATA$`.